# Switching focus between editor and terminal in Kate

Tags: unix, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, kate

When working in Unix with various programming languages I often use Kate as my primary editor.
It has a really nice function of being able to open a built-in terminal window which is quite useful.

The problem is that switching back and forth to the terminal view using a mouse is quite a pain and I can't find any shortcuts for this. The only shortcut I could find is for closing the entire terminal (not just changing the focus). This is a bit annoying as it causes the text in the terminal window to get truncated (I think it's a known Kate bug).

Does anyone know a better shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the Kate bug has [been fixed](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157523). The correct answer to this question is now `F4`.

Comment: Unfortunately is not working for me out of the box, however it can be configured in shortcuts, works great!. Kubuntu 16.10

Comment: This is working for me in Ubuntu 20.04. It's not very obvious though where there focus is, just a slight change to the cursors. This initially made me think it wasn't working.

Answer (score 5):

There's a "Focus Terminal" shortcut in the "Configure shortcuts"

There you can set it up. F4 didn't work by default in my case and Shift+Tab worked only in one direction.

Answer (score 3):

this is a [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157523) in kate. possible workarounds: a) [shift back by pressing Shift+Tab](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=169748#c8), b) try another shortcut ([some do work](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157523#c6)). see also [Bug 157496: Alt+[Key] shortcuts for menu items do not work](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157496).

Comment: Yeah, they have a lot of bugs. Unfortunately, Shift+Tab didn't work. The only thing that seems to work for now is the shortcut that toggles the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Today (Kate v 22.08.2), it's
Settings > Configure Keyboard Shortcuts > Type "terminal" in Search box >
edit shortcut for **"Focus Terminal Panel"**.
For me, the default was Ctrl+Shift+ F4, while F4 hid the terminal.
I swapped them because it's more convenient for me.
The focus shift is only visible by appearance of the cursor changing slightly.

[image: Screenshot of shortcut settings]